# Weird issues with reactivity in nuxt.js

Tags: javascript, vue.js, nuxt.js

I'm migrating my project from vue.js to nuxt.js but I'm running into some really weird issues with reactivity in Nuxt. basically I have code that gets data from my database and stores it in data attributes the issue is in my HTML I have some mustaches linked to the data attributes but for some reason, it's just displaying the default value I set the data too. I know the data changed because if I go into the vue developer tools I can see that the data has changed. Does anybody know how to fix this?

index.vue - css:

```
<template>
  <div id="masterdiv">
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.0/jquery.min.js" integrity="sha256-xNzN2a4ltkB44Mc/Jz3pT4iU1cmeR0FkXs4pru/JxaQ=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.4.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha256-oKpAiD7qu3bXrWRVxnXLV1h7FlNV+p5YJBIr8LOCFYw=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <Header />
      <div id="section1" >
      <h1 data-lax-preset="fadeInOut zoomInOut" class="title lax" style="color:#53c875;">‎‏‏‎‎Hi, I'm Max. I build‏‏‎ amazing

        <br />‏‏‎ ‎
        <span class="describertext" style="font-size:32px !important">GAMES | WEBSITES | CIRCUITS</span>
        <span
     class="txt-rotate"
     data-period="2000"
     style="color:#53c875 !important"
     data-rotate='["games.","websites.","circuits."]'></span>
      </h1>
      <button @mouseover="vhover" @mouseleave="vnhover" @click="VMWORK" data-lax-preset="fadeInOut" class="btn btn-info lax vmwork"><i class="fas fa-eye" style="margin-right:5px;"></i>View my work</button>
    </div>
    <div id="section2" >
      <h2 class="lax subtitle" data-lax-preset="fadeInOut" style="color:#53c875;font-size:60px;">About Me</h2>
      <img src="headshot.png" class="lax" data-lax-preset="fadeInOut" width="120" height="120" style="margin-bottom:20px;"/>
      <p
        class="lax aboutText"
        data-lax-preset="fadeInOut"
        style="color:#53c875;font-size:16px; "
      >Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Nisl pretium fusce id velit ut tortor pretium. Aliquet risus feugiat in ante metus. Etiam tempor orci eu lobortis elementum nibh tellus. Elementum eu facilisis sed odio morbi quis commodo. Amet consectetur adipiscing elit ut aliquam purus sit. Mi quis hendrerit dolor magna eget est lorem ipsum dolor. Etiam tempor orci eu lobortis elementum nibh tellus molestie nunc. Nibh tellus molestie nunc non blandit. Ultrices eros in cursus turpis massa.</p>
    </div>
    <div id="section3" >
      <h2 class="subtitle" style="color:#53c875;margin-bottom:20px;font-size:60px;">My Projects</h2>
      <!-- Page Content -->
      <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
           <div v-for="item in Titles" class="Project" :key="item.id">
           <a class="img-container">
            <img class="img-fluid ProjectImg" :src="item.Image" data-toggle="modal" :data-target="item.Modal"/>
           </a>
          </div> 
        </div>

      </div>

      <!-- /.container -->
    </div>
    <div id="section4" >
      <h2 class="subtitle" style="color:#53c875;font-size:60px;" >Contact Me</h2>

    <div class="messages"></div>

    <div class="controls">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <input id="form_email" type="email" name="email" class="form-control" placeholder="Your Email"
                    v-model="email" 
                    required="required" >
                    <div ></div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-6">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <textarea id="form_message" name="message" class="form-control" placeholder="Your Message" 
                    v-model="message"
                    rows="4" required="required" ></textarea>
                    <div></div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-12">
                <input type="submit" style="border-radius:5px !important" @click="SendEmail" class="btn  btn-primary col-md-12"

                >
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    </div>
    <!-- The Modal -->
    <div class="modal"  id="myModal">
      <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content" style="background-color:#071b45">
          <!-- Modal Header -->
          <img src="Game.jpg" alt />
          <hr>
          <h2 class="modal-title" style="margin-left:11px;color:#fff">{{ Titles[0].Title }}</h2>
          <!-- Modal body -->
          <div class="modal-body" style="text-align:left;">
            <p style="color:#fff">
              {{ Console }}
            </p>
          </div>

          <!-- Modal footer -->
          <div class="modal-footer">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="modal"  id="ARD">
      <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content" style="background-color:#071b45">
          <!-- Modal Header -->
          <img src="Ard.jpg" alt />
          <hr>
          <h2 class="modal-title" style="margin-left:11px;color:#fff">{{ Titles[1].Title }}</h2>
          <!-- Modal body -->
          <div class="modal-body" style="text-align:left;">
            <p style="color:#fff">
              {{ Arduino }}
            </p>
          </div>

          <!-- Modal footer -->
          <div class="modal-footer">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="modal"  id="SOAP">
      <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content" style="background-color:#071b45">
          <!-- Modal Header -->
          <img src="Soap.jpg" alt />
          <hr>
          <h2 class="modal-title" style="margin-left:11px;color:#fff">{{ Titles[3].Title }}</h2>
          <!-- Modal body -->
          <div class="modal-body" style="text-align:left;">
            <p style="color:#fff">
              {{ Soap }}
            </p>
          </div>

          <!-- Modal footer -->
          <div class="modal-footer">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="modal"  id="SWW">
      <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content" style="background-color:#071b45">
          <!-- Modal Header -->
          <img src="SWW_BIG.png" alt />
          <hr>
          <h2 class="modal-title" style="margin-left:11px;color:#fff">{{ Titles[2].Title }}</h2>
          <!-- Modal body -->
          <div class="modal-body" style="text-align:left;">
            <p style="color:#fff">
              {{ SWW }}
            </p>
          </div>

          <!-- Modal footer -->
          <div class="modal-footer">
            <button @click="GotoStarWars" data-dismiss="modal" class="btn btn-info">View</button>
            <button type="button"  class="btn btn-danger" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <link
      rel="stylesheet"
      href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css"
    />
    <footer style="background-color:#143a5a;height:100px;margin-top:-10px;">
      <h4 style="color:#fff;">MAXWELL CAMPBELL <span style="color:#53c875;">©2020</span></h4>
    </footer>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.13.0/css/all.min.css" integrity="sha256-h20CPZ0QyXlBuAw7A+KluUYx/3pK+c7lYEpqLTlxjYQ=" crossorigin="anonymous" />
  </div>
</template>
<script>
import Bound from 'bounds.js'
//import SendEmailService from '@/services/main'
import Swal from 'sweetalert2'

import lax from 'lax.js'

import anime from 'animejs/lib/anime.es.js';

import ScrollOut from "scroll-out";
// Initialize Firebase
//var ImagesList = ["images/Small/Ard_Small.jpg","images/Small/Game_Small.jpg","SWW_SMALL.png","Soap_Small.jpg"]
////////////////////////////////////////////////
//////////////////
import * as firebase from 'firebase/app'
import 'firebase/database'
import Header from "@/components/Header.vue";
export default {
  name: "home",
  components: {
    Header
  },
  data() {
    return {
      Arduino: 'Error',
      Titles: [
        { Title: 'Console', Image: 'Game_Small.jpg', Modal: "#myModal", Id: 0 },
        { Title: 'ByteBeat', Image: 'Ard_Small.jpg', Modal: "#ARD", Id: 1 },
        { Title: 'Star Wars Weather', Image: 'SWW_SMALL.png', Modal: "#SWW", Id: 2 },
        { Title: 'Soap', Image: 'Soap_Small.jpg', Modal: "#SOAP", Id: 3 },
      ],
      SWW: 'Error',
      Soap: 'Error',
      Console: 'Error',
      email: '',
      message: ''
    }
  },
  methods: {
    VMWORK(){
      document.getElementById("section3").scrollIntoView({behavior:"smooth"});
    },
    // async SendEmail() {
    //   const response = await SendEmailService.register({
    //     email: this.email,
    //     message: this.message
    //   })
    //   console.log(response);
    //   Swal.fire('Success', 'Your email is being processed', 'success')
    // },
    ReadData() {
      var test;
      return firebase.database().ref('/Json').once('value').then(test =(snapshot) => {
        var st = (snapshot.val() && snapshot.val().Projects);
        console.log(st);
        this.Titles[0].Title = st["0"].Title;
        this.Titles[1].Title = st["1"].Title;
        this.Titles[2].Title = st["2"].Title;
        this.Titles[3].Title = st["3"].Title;
        this.Soap = st["3"].Description;
        this.Arduino = st["1"].Description;
        this.Console = st["0"].Description;
        this.SWW = st["2"].Description;
      });
    },
    vhover(){
      console.log("button hover!");
      anime({
        targets: '.vmwork',
        scale: 1.2
      });
    },
    vnhover(){
      anime({
        targets: '.vmwork',
        scale: 1
      });
    },
    GotoStarWars(){
      console.log("SWW");
      this.$router.push({
        path: '/SWW'
      })
    }
  },
  mounted () {
    this.ReadData()
  }
};

</script>
```

Comment: Can you try doing `this.Titles = [... this.Titles]` after modifying it?

Comment: might want to consider watcher or computed

Comment: Vue is not reactive when setting array values explicitly via the index. 
https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/reactivity.html#For-Arrays

Comment: @Adam He isn't setting any array value. He updates an object

Comment: @Orkhan Alikhanov what do you mean? Can you give an example?

Comment: @Karl if I used a computed property wouldn't I have to have multiple computed properties. One for every time I need to get data wich seems inefficient.

Comment: @maxall4, are you mainly referring to the data named Titles?

Comment: @Karl I'm referring to the separate data properties Arduino, Soap, Sww, and Console

Comment: nvm i figured it out